# Мостик между VPN и локальной сетью на прокси

Tags: vpn

Здравствуйте. Итак, у нас стоит сервер. У него одна сетевая карта, через которую он подключен VPN-ом к удаленному офису и по прокси к локальной сети. Мне нужно из машин локальной сети получить доступ к удаленному серверу (VPN). В случае с двумя сетевыми картами ясно - нужно создать мост. А вот как сделать с одной сетевой картой?

***Так, задача поменялась. Мы поставили отдельный комп с двумя сетками. По одной сетке подключен к VPN, по другой к локальной сети. IP VPN назначен вручную(172.16.27.252), а другой сетки автоматом(192.168.1.47). Создал мост. На другой машине прописал маршрут route add -p 172.16.0.0 mask 255.255.0.0 192.168.0.0. Но эта машина все таки не видит сеть 172.16... Может не так настроил?***

Comment: Видеть и не будет, потому что разные подсети (из одной подсети попасть в другую можно только через VPN). Так же освети полностью задачу. Если VPN 172.16.27.252 - это интернет и тебе его надо пересылать в подсеть 192.168.1.47 - это одно решение, а если тебе нужен просто доступ к определенным сервисам то это другое решение. Просто в том что ты просишь, получается "Как попасть из Москвы в Питер, причем сразу (не садясь в поезд/самолет/11 маршрут и т.д.)"

Comment: Мне нужен был доступ к конкретному сервису через 172.16.27.252. У нас в другом офисе стоит веб-сервер и мне нужно было попасть туда. Я уже решил проблему. Просто в настройках сетевому адаптера с IP 172.16.27.252 расшарил интернет и все. А в регистре прописал ключ IPEnableRouter. Но теперь другая проблема. Чтобы попасть на тот веб-сервер вбиваем IP. Как правило это неудобно.  У нас стоит сервер и там ISA Server. Сеть НЕ доменная. Создана на рабочей группе. Мне нужно сопоставить IP с доменным именем. Можно и через hosts на каждом компе, но это долго. Хотелось бы на сервере как-то решить это.

Comment: Ну тут только прописывать обратную доменную зону, но есть нет контролера домена, это сделать никак. Есть ли DNS сервер?Если да, то в нем можно прописать обратную зону. Ну или на крайний случай написать bat файл, который добавит сайт в файл Host (для автоматизации процесса добавиления)

Answer (score 2):

Можно и на одном интерфейсе создать vpnи присылать трафик

Answer (score 0):

В мост можно объединить физический интерфейс с VPN интерфейсом. Детали реализации зависят от операционной системы

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас в качестве роутера используется Mikrotik, то на PPP-Profiles у вас должен быть настроен профиль, наподобие этого, где LA - виртуальная сеть для туннеля. RA: это пул адресов виртуальной сети 10.100.11.0/28

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно должен быть создан Secret с указанием этого профиля.
В настройках IP-Firewall-NAT нужно создать маскарадинг. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня создано так, с той лишь разницей что в качестве VPN используется L2TP/IPSec. При подключении клиента по L2TP, он получает адрес из диапазона виртуальной сети 10.100.11.0/28
И благодаря маскарадингу, я имею возможность обращаться между подсетями 192.168.1.0/24 к 10.100.11.0/28 в обоих направлениях.
Добавлю только, что в правилах маскарадинга у меня указан Out.Interface: pppoe, чтобы иметь возможность соединять сети через интернет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В вашем случае это будет скорее всего eth1 (LAN)